# caanot authenticate via a web browser

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I build application android with ionic 2 but I have this error when I launch application in my smartphone:

this is tuto of application : 
https://medium.com/appseed-io/third-party-authentication-for-your-ionic-2-mobile-app-9fdd43169deb

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting this error when you are trying to login using Google+ because Google has updated there API's and you can use that with Cordova plugin for ionic application. I suggest you to use: "cordova-plugin-googleplus". I was also following the same tutorial but completed it using the cordova plugin following this [tutorial](https://www.djamware.com/post/59094a2280aca7414e78a63d/ionic-3-google-plus-authentication-tutorial).